# Getting Full Lives

Tags: candy-crush-saga

Is it just me or is *Candy Crush Saga* one of the greediest games ever conceived? Every single aspect of this game costs something... Want more levels? Well you have to wait... or you can be impulsive and pay up...

http://rndgames.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/113_1_1_182239217.jpg

Well I am tired of giving that glutton of a girl my hard-earned cash. I have already forked over enough money to put my child through college *(not literally)*. That being said, is there any way to get full lives without having to:

- wait 2.5 hours
- pay $0.99
- use a third-party application 
  ?

Comment: Reason for downvote? I looked to [meta regarding cheats](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games), so I fail to see why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found a reliable way to get full lives.

[image]
<sub>(source: [alimartell.com](http://www.alimartell.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/no-more-lives-candy-crush.png))</sub>

When this happens, do the following:

#### On Android

> - Go to `Settings > System > Date and time`:
>
>   > [image]
> - Change the time to 3 hours later:
>
>   > [image]

#### On IPhone:

> - Go to `General > Date & Time`:
>
>   > http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/b/b4/Change-Date-and-Time-on-the-iPhone-Step-5.jpg/350px-Change-Date-and-Time-on-the-iPhone-Step-5.jpg
> - Change the time to 3 hours later

Next go back into *Candy Crush Saga* and confirm that the lives have reset:
[image]

Finally, go back into to your `Date & Time` settings and change the time back to normal.
Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Given how integrated the game is with Facebook I'm really surprised it uses the device's time to determine when to give more lives. What happens when you set the clock back to normal?

Comment: The timer starts when you lose 1 life, so if you set the timer back after you lose a life (say 3 hours), you could wait a 180 minutes rather than the 30 per life.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of getting a lot of lives would be like using 2 Facebook accounts. Though it's a cheat, it works and you can gift and trade lives once you run out.