# Moving on in Candy Crush

Tags: candy-crush-saga

In playing the mystery quest game in *Candy Crush Saga* to unlock level 36, I understand it as I have to play and win 3 games, one game a day. If I don't win, say the first mystery quest game the first time I try, can I keep trying until I win that day or do I have to wait 24 hours before I can play that game again? In other words do I get one shot at it each day?

Answer (score 2):

You can try as many times as you like, but once you complete the level, you need to wait.

I literally just posted [an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127930/get-full-lives-without-paying/127931#127931) on how to get full lives instantly.  The same concept would apply here...If you wanted to play multiple quests per day, you can change the date to tomorrow in your `Date & Time` settings and you will be able to do multiple mystery quests. Just make sure to change the date back.  Hope this helps!