# Is there a way to reset time for next quest/life regeneration?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have the Candy Crush app on my iPhone 4. I have completed to Level 50 and done the first two mystery quests to go to the next level. I was getting ready to do the third quest and it tells me that I can't do any more quests today and have to wait until the time regenerates. The time to next quest says "383024:07:04" (and it is counting down). My life regeneration says I have no more lives but in "22982099:52" I can get another one.

Can someone please tell me if there is any way to reset this time issue without losing all my levels?

Comment: The question is fine. I just want to let you know that you don't have to sign your questions. Your tag does that for you.

Comment: I answered that before http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127930/getting-full-lives/127931#127931

Answer (score 2):

Set the clock on your phone manually, apparently to the year 4617.  No that can't be right.  Are you sure you copied the time until next life down properly?  In any case, if you set the time on your phone to be after the point when you'd have full lives (that's important), you can reset it to the current time and still keep your lives.  Candy Crush doesn't do any checking to see if the time has been changed, and does a simple date difference if it's waiting to grant another life.